# Return null from SUBSTRING if substring not found

Tags: sql, null, substring

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(campaign_name,CHARINDEX(‘[’,campaign_name)+1,
(((LEN(campaign_name))-CHARINDEX(‘]’,REVERSE(campaign_name)))-
CHARINDEX(‘[’,campaign_name))) as campaign_code
FROM table
```

This code currently gives me the substring between '[' and ']' from the field campaign_name. However, for a couple of entries in the campaign_name field there is no '[' or ']'. In these cases, the above code returns the whole string in the field. Instead I want to return NULL but at the moment I have been unable to execute this. I would love some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(‘[’,campaign_name) = 0 or CHARINDEX(‘]’,campaign_name) = 0 THEN null ELSE SUBSTRING(campaign_name,CHARINDEX(‘[’,campaign_name)+1,
(((LEN(campaign_name))-CHARINDEX(‘]’,REVERSE(campaign_name)))-
CHARINDEX(‘[’,campaign_name))) END as campaign_code
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't specify a database engine; I'm assuming SQL Server from the syntax.

The `SUBSTRING` function will return `NULL` when one of its inputs is `NULL`, so we can make use of the `NULLIF()` function to null out fields that don't match the pattern (i.e. those for which `CHARINDEX == 0`).

```
DECLARE @WORDS TABLE (
 Word VARCHAR(MAX)
);
INSERT INTO @WORDS VALUES ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
INSERT INTO @WORDS VALUES ('xyzzy');
INSERT INTO @WORDS VALUES ('la de dah');
INSERT INTO @WORDS VALUES ('redefine');
INSERT INTO @WORDS VALUES ('definitely');

DECLARE @SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(MAX) = 'def';
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(Word,NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING,Word),0),LEN(@SEARCHSTRING)) as Result 
FROM @WORDS
```

```
+------+
|Result|
+------+
| def  |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| def  |
| def  |
+------+
```